# How to write a click function on the point plotted using angular-google-charts-npm

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I want to add a click on the plotted point of where, what, how and when. Like I want the 'Where' , 'What', 'How' and 'When' points to act as a click button . I am using angular-google-charts - npm.

[image: angular-google-chart]
drawChart

My Code is -

```
private drawChart(){

    let data = this.gLib.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Aspect', 'Splash'],
          ['Where',  1    ],
          ['What',   2    ],
          ['How',    3    ],
          ['When',   4    ]
    ]);
    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
    'width':400,
    'height':300};


    var chart:any = new this.gLib.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('divLineChart'));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', this.selectHandler);
    chart.draw(data, options);
    chart.draw(data);

    
  }
  selectHandler() {
    var chart:any = new this.gLib.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('divLineChart'));
    let data = this.gLib.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Aspect', 'Splash'],
        ['Where',   1    ],
        ['What',    2    ],
        ['How',     3    ],
        ['When',    4    ]
  ]);
  
    var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[1];
    console.log("selectedItem = ", selectedItem)
   
    var value = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 1);
    console.log("value = ", value);
    alert('The user selected ' + value);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the documentation of the package there seem to be a couple of [events](https://github.com/FERNman/angular-google-charts#events) that may help you with that. Namely [select](https://github.com/FERNman/angular-google-charts#select) seem to be the most appropriate.